# jQuery way to handle select lists, radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I handle HTML form elements with jQuery, I always end up with an ugly mix of jQuery syntax and plain JavaScript like, e.g.:

```
function doStuff($combo){
    if( $combo.get(0).options[$combo.get(0).selectedIndex].value=="" ){
        var txt = "";
    }else{
        var txt = $combo.get(0).options[$combo.get(0).selectedIndex].text;
    }
    var $description = $combo.closest("div.item").find("input[name$=\[description\]]");
    $description.val(txt);
}
```

Are there standard jQuery methods to handle typical operations on elements like `<select>`, `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">`?

With *typical*, I mean stuff like reading the value of the selected radio button in a group or replacing elements in a selection list. I haven't found them in the documentation but I admit that method overloading can make doc browser kind of tricky.

### Update

Thanks everyone. Once in the right track, I figured out myself the rest of the stuff. E.g., I can handle a `<select>` list like any other DOM tree:

```
$("select")
    .empty()
    .append('<option value="">(Pick one)</option><option value="a">Option A</option><option value="b">Option B</option>');
```

Comment: This is jquery? I thought you needed to put parentheses around selectors... Edit: nvm, just realized that's supposed to be a variable with the dollar sign in front of it.

Comment: @dclowd9901: yep, sorry, it's only some little Hungarian notation - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: Yeah, I need to remember to separate the idea that `$` is inherently a jQuery exclusive tag. You'd think it'd come naturally as a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to simplify your code a lot. Here are a few examples of working with form elements:

### `<input type="text">`

```
$(':text') // select all text boxes
$('input#example').val(); // gets value of a text box
```

### `<input type="checkbox">`

```
$(':checkbox') // selects all checkboxes
$('input.example:checked') // selects all ticked checkboxes with class 'example'
$('#example').is(':checked'); // true if checkbox with ID 'example' is ticked
```

### `<input type="radio">`

```
$(':radio') // selects all radio buttons
$(':radio:checked').each( function() {
    $(this).val(); // gets value of each selected radio button
});
$('input:radio[name="asdf"]'); // gets particular group of radio buttons
```

### `<select>`

```
$('select#example').change( function() {
    // this part runs every time the drop down is changed
    $(this).val(); // gets the selected value
});
```

See also http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/ for more selectors.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want the **text** and not the **value**, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for that `<option>` (find it using the [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)), like this:

```
function doStuff($combo){
  var txt = $combo.children("option:selected").text();
  $combo.closest("div.item").find("input[name$=\[description\]]").val(txt);
}
```

If you wanted the value part of `<option value="4" selected>Four</option>` then you could use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
var val = $combo.val();
```

Answer (score 3):

For `<select>` elements, you should be able to just get the value (with `.val()`).  For radio buttons, you can do this:

```
$('input:radio[name=whatever]:checked').val()
```

Checkboxes are similar:

```
$('#checkboxId:checked').val()
```

Those two will be null if things are unchecked (though with radio buttons it's kind-of evil for that to be the case).

*edit* see Nick's answer for getting the text of a selected option instead of the value (basically call `.text()` instead of `.val()`).

Answer (score 0):

For selects you can use the `val()` method. In case of multiple select the `val()` method returns an array of the selected options.

For checkboxes and radio you can grab all the selected checkboxes using the `:checked` selector.

You'll find all the details as well as examples at the jQuery site : http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

For `Select` elements, you should be able to just get the value (with `.val()`). For `radio buttons`, you can do this:

```
$('input:radio[name=whatever]:checked').val()
```

Checkboxes are similar:

```
$('#checkboxId:checked').val()
```

Those two will be null if things are unchecked (though with radio buttons it's kind-of evil for that to be the case).

edit see Nick's answer for getting the text of a selected option instead of the value (basically call `.text()` instead of `.val()`).

Ignore formatting....i havent done that..;)